# MVC6 Connection Strings for SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I was using MVC5 Entity Framework for a long time with connection string in `web.config` that look like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="GuestContext" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DAVESQLSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NexDec12;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=changeME!;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am trying to figure out how to do this in the `appsettings.json` file. I am learning MVC6 using Rick Anderson's tutorial [here](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html).

Rather than use the built in SQL Server in VS or IIS10 I want to connect to my external SQL Server Express. I have tried this but it doesn't work, says the login is invalid for user `sa` (so it's trying to use the correct username?) I feel like it isn't using the correct password but I don't know how to construct a connnection string for the new MVC6 json config format.

I tried this:

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=DAVESQLSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MovieTut;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=changeME!"
    }
```

Comment: The problem was I hadn't initiatred database migrations.  Previously with MVC5 EF6 I never had to use migrations unless I was going to change my schema.  It seems with MVC6 EF7 you DO have to initialize migrations.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a different structure to your config.json, like so (notice "ConnectionString element in both connection declarations)

EDITED to add format to the code

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
"EmployeeContext": {
        "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=Manish_Database;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two connection strings are not equal: the one that for MVC 6 contains "Trusted_Connection=True" but still wants to use "sa" as user. You have to choose between Windows and SQL authentications. See [Choose an Authentication Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) and update your connection string accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you have chosen to 'name' your connection string in the json version.

Try changing the value `"ConnectionString"` to `"GuestContext"`

```
"Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "GuestContext": "Server=DAVESQLSERVER\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MovieTut;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true; Integrated Security=false;User ID=sa;Password=changeME!"
    }
```

Also, I would expect for this to be defined in `config.json` rather than `appsettings.json` (but I think that may be configurable).

Comment: I don't think so, because my app is calling the Default Connection in the Startup.cs file, so I feel like if i input my connection string into default connection it should work...will see and try the alternate method you suggested.

Comment: Does your `startup.cs` have a step for configuring your DB context?  If so, what is full 'key' it is using to retrieve the connection string.  That portion might look something like this: `configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString")` (to match the json from your post).