# Using multiple connection strings

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, connection-string

**Info**
I have multiple projects in my Solution, of which one is the DAL and the other is an ASP.NET MVC6 project.
Since the MVC6 project is also the startup project I need to add my connection string there.

I saw [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34324921/mvc6-connection-strings-for-sql-server-express), but it is not accepted, nor does it work.

**My Try**
*appsettings.json*

```
"Data": {
  "DefaultConnection": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bar;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "FooBar": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bar;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]))
             .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:FooBar:ConnectionString"]));
}
```

Yet, when I try to access data using the `FooBar` connection string I get the following message:

> "Additional information: No connection string named 'FooBar' could be
>   found in the application config file."

**The Question**
How do I get multiple connection strings working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take a look at the [official documentation for connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core) in asp.net core their example shows the connection string stored in `appsettings.json` like this

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BloggingDatabase": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp.NewDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
}
```

Which, when adapted to your example would become.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bar;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "FooBar": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bar;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Configuring the context in `Startup.cs` with the configuration string being read from configuration would use the `GetConnectionString()` method with the configuration key

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    // Add framework services.
    services
        .AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnextionString("DefaultConnection")))
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnextionString("FooBar")));
}
```

Now one observed issue with how the above context is configured in the original question is that there are now two connection strings for the same context.

Trying to use multiple connection strings to work for the same context will cause problems as the framework would not know which option to use when requesting the context.

Comment: The second part doesn't work.
I get an error on 'Configuration.GetConnectionString' stating:  'IConfigurationRoot' does not contain a definition for 'GetConnectionString' and no extension method 'GetConnectionString' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfigurationRoot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: what version of asp.net are you using. check to make sure you are not omitting a `using` namespace

Comment: Neither does the first part it seems, I get a ArgumentNullException pointing at  DefaultConnnection in the startupfile

Comment: how can I see which version I'm using? ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Comment: when you created project, what template did you use

Comment: I added a new project to my solution and I took ASP.NET Web Aplication
Then I took ASP.NET 5 > Web Application

Comment: ok then the code you showed is different cause that code is for asp.net core not asp.net 5. the documentation i cited is for asp.net core

Comment: I've deleted my project and created another one, this time an ASP.NET 4.5.1 MVC Template :) Thank you for your time & effort.

Comment: In this case, which db will be used? Both?

Answer (score 0):

what you need for configuration in .net core 3.x is something like this
or you have Iconfiguration injected in startup (This is for a command line project with args).

```
        IConfiguration Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
       .AddEnvironmentVariables()
       .AddCommandLine(args)
       .Build();

        string conString = Microsoft
               .Extensions
               .Configuration
               .ConfigurationExtensions
               .GetConnectionString(Configuration, "ConnectionName");
```

and then you need to do this last bit for all connection strings you need to use.