# Two connections ASP.NET Core, EF core, ArgumentNullException error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, connection-string

I have two projects in my Solution, of which one is the Identity registration  and the other is an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I have added another connection for Identity accordingly to [official documentation for connection strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core) in appsettings.json. But I have got exception System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll in ConfigureServices method.

My changed appsettings.json

```html
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=employeedb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "LocalConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=employeedb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection"]);
            })
        .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:LocalConnection"]); 
        });

        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
        {
            mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
        });
        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(mapper);

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
    }
```

Exception in ConfigureServices method

[image]

How do I get two connection strings working in ConfigureServices method?

Comment: Don't post images of error messages. Post it as text (together with a stack trace).

Comment: Probably `Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection"]` is null. Also, what is `Configuration` anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525856/using-multiple-connection-strings)

Comment: it`s not duplicate I have another problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Data:DefaultConnection` element in your appsettings.json file. Instead, try using `Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]`. This counts for `LocalConnection` as well.

Even easier might be to use the `GetConnectionString()` extension method. For example:

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
```